# AngularJs : Variable from directive to controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can pass the variable itemSelect inside my directive to my controller?

```
mDirective.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            options: "="
        },
        templateUrl: '',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {  
                .........               
             $(element).find('.typeY').on('change', function() {
                var itemSelect =   $(element).find('.typeY').val();
            });
        } ,

    };
});
```

Comment: You can explain more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
mDirective.directive('directive', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            options: "=",
            selected:"=",
        },
        templateUrl: '',

        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {  
                .........               
            $(element).find('.typeY').on('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                  scope.selected=value;  // value from the element
                });
            });
        } ,

    };
});
```

At html level

`<div directive options='expression' selected='expressionToTheScopeProperty'/>`